# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in two DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My web.xml states dispatcher-servlet url pattern as:

```
<!-- root context -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
</servlet>

<!-- admin context -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>adminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/admin-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>adminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

two servlet-mapping files are described as

```
 <!--servlet-context.xml for appServlet-->
<annotation-driven />
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
<!--admin-context.xml for adminServlet-->
<annotation-driven />
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/admin/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

and I coded two controllers for the test. one is ok but the other met "error"

```
@Controller("admin.IndexController")
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminIndexController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    ... 
    return "index";         
    //I thought this location will be /myContext/WEB-INF/view/admin/index.jsp
    //and it run well
    }
}
```

but the following controller couldn't find it's next page.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AddCategoryController {
    @RequestMapping(value={"/category/add"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String form(Model model){
         ...
        return "addCategory"; 
        //I thought the location will be /myContext/WEB-INF(/view/admin/category/)index.jsp
        //but Spring forwarded to /myContext/WEB-INF/view/addCategory.jsp

    }
}
```

if I write the code as "return admin/index;" this has no problem.

But I think AddCategoryController has to be handled by adminServlet and admin-context.xml.
Because AddCategoryController calls addCategory.jsp as the way of relative path, so they both should be on the same path. but I met fail... Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Can you show the error you are getting ? I am not sure but are you allowed to give same RequestMapping to the 2 or more classes. I doubt that.

Comment: there are no special errors in the console of the web container. just 404 error. the browser  tries to find the page in /myContext/WEB-INF/view/, not in /myContext/WEB-INF/view/admin/.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve everything by registering servlet only once. Do not know why you are registering DispatcherServlet twice. You can give the root jsp folder path like "/WEB-INF/view/ and then in code you can move to different jsps in subfolders like /admin/index.jsp

Comment: I know I can achieve everything by only one dispatchServlet. but An web application can be extended and we need to manage it by logical partitions. Spring framework gives us this features too. I wanted to test it.